# Flutter Duplicate Globalkey in wiget tree issue when nva

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have an app that uses `Getx`. I have three pages. Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3. The navigation is like this-

Page 1 => Page 2 => Page 3 => Page 1.

Page 1 has following code

```
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageOneBuilder(context).build();
  }
}

class PageOneBuilder {
   PageOneBuilder(this.context);
   BuildContext context;

  final controller = Get.put(PageOneController());
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //------------------- other codes here ---------------
}
```

There is a button in `Page 1`, upon clicking following is executed

```
Get.to(() => const PageTwo());
```

And from page two, button click leads to third page,

```
Get.to(() => const PageThree());
```

And lastly from page three, back to page 1 like this

```
Get.to(() => const PageOne());
```

**Problem:**
When i click button on page three to get back to page one, I get following error:-

> Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use.
`Get.off()` instead of `Get.to`.